# flake8 is not picking up global configuration file in user directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8

I have flake8 installed in pipenv virtual environments on per project basis.

The flake8 docs state that:

> Values set at the command line have highest priority, then those in
> the project configuration file, then those in your user directory, and
> finally there are the defaults.

As per the docs I created two .flake8 files:

1. In the project root - for per project configuration
2. /Users/rusl/.config/flake8/.flake8 - for global configuration

When I run flake8 it picks up configuration options from a local file, but it completely ignores the global file.

How can I make flake8 see the global configuration file so I don't have to repeat some configuration options in every project?

Comment: The global configuration is `~/.config/flake8`. That's a file, not a directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This answer is for flake8 < 4.0.0**.
For flake8 4.0.0 and up, see [farnsy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73604198/2745495).

---

It can be a bit misleading, but the [User Configuration](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html#user-configuration) section of the flake8 docs does mention a **file**:

> Flake8 allows a user to use “global” configuration **file** to store
> preferences.
>
> ...
>
> Note that **Flake8** looks for `~\.flake8` on Windows and `~/.config/flake8`
> on Linux and other Unix systems.

As [answered in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66294383/flake8-is-not-picking-up-global-configuration-file-in-user-directory#comment117209263_66294383), `~/.config/flake8` should be a file, not a directory.

Comment: It definitely mislead me! )) although the absence of the slash should have given me a hint!

Comment: Please see @farnsy's answer, and update this answer accordingly.  Flake8 no longer loads a global configuration file.  The section is removed from the documentation as well.

Answer (score 18):

Note that as of flake8 4.0, [flake8 no longer supports a global config file](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/release-notes/4.0.0.html#backwards-incompatible-changes) at all. I don't know what could motivate such a horrible idea, but that's where we are.

Lots of docs are not up to date on this, so maybe this answer will help guide some people who think flake8 is ignoring their global config due to user error. It's not you, it's them.

Comment: A terrible decision, I've spent already an hour today on broken tools so far =\

Comment: Time to switch to Ruff I guess, I've only heard good things about it